# Ways to earn ETH passive income

Tags: dapps, security, defi, staking

I have a decent amount of ETH in my cold wallet (<32 ETH). These bag of ETH is my HODL bag, meaning that I don't want to spend it and I am planning to hold it for the next 10-20 years.

What are my options in terms of putting these ETH to work in a fully secured fashion? I am willing to sacrifice yield for safety.

More specifically,

1. Is my safest option to stake ETH? If so, what pooling staking protocol is the safest (since I don't have 32)?
2. Are there other fixed/variable APY options for me to consider that are similar to or safer than option 1 above? As an example, I was looking at Element.fi for fixed interest or other DeFi lending protocols

Answer (score 0):

Staking eth is by far the best option. Using an LSD like Lido would be the easiest solution, or you could use a more decentralized option like Rocketpool or solo-validating. This is going to be your highest "risk-free" yield you can get.

Any other defi protocol is going to have hacking risk among others which translate to a significant chance of losing your money in 10-20 years.

Answer (score 0):

For staking ETH, check out [Stakewise liquid staking](https://stakewise.io/).

Liquid staking allows you stake and withdraw without delays.

There is never yield without risk. To make profit, you need to be ready to accept some risk. Whether this risk is obivous like volatility risk, or technical like smart contract risk, it's outside the scope of this question.